# Using invalid HTML that is replaced on page load

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Would there be anything wrong with using invalid HTML on pages that is replaced by valid HTML using JS when the page loads (e.g., `<tag italic>Whatever</tag>` → `<a class="tag" href="/tag/whatever"><i>Whatever</i></a>`)?

Comment: According to Google this wouldn't affect search rankings (https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-john-mueller-we-do-not-use-w3c-validation-in-search-results/355114/#); would it affect anything else?

Comment: My advise is to use valid HTML anyway because it is not hard to do and if something has a problem with valid HTML it is that things fault and not yours.